# Returning list of elements with Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mono, flux, spring-webflux

I'am trying to create a simple example of a CRUD with Spring Webflux, but I'am getting *stucked* in some concepts.

I know that I can return a Flux in my controller request mapping method. But sometimes I would like to return a 404 status, so I can handle in the front-end somehow.

I found a example in the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-reactive-feature-overview) to use the ServerResponse object:

```
        public Mono<ServerResponse> listPeople(ServerRequest request) { 
                Flux<Person> people = repository.allPeople();
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(people, Person.class);
        }
```

As you can see, even when the return is a list (Flux) o *persons*, the ServerResponse.ok.body creates a Mono.

So my question: Is that the way it is? In other words, it does not matter if I have a Flux, does Spring always return a **Mono** of ServerResponse (or other similar class)?

For my 404 status I could use something like

```
.switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

But I was thinking in something more *streaming* way. That I could handle the list of objects element by element, for instance.

Comment: The `ServerResponse` is always a single element, hence a mono, what is returned inside that `ServerResponse` can be a flux and that is also what should happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for your answer. But I'm not getting how to return some http status. Every example uses

        @GetMapping("/person")
        Flux<Person> list() {
                return this.repository.findAll();
        }

and not with the usual ResponseEntity object, that could contain a status.

Comment: @IgorVeloso your latest comment suggest you're using WebFlux annotation model, but your question suggests the functional one. Could you edit your question to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @BrianClozel, that´s the real problem, In my question, I used the example in the official Spring doc, but I want to return a Http Status (let´s say 404). In my comment I´ve just written another example I had found on web, but without the http status either. Sorry if I'am not being clear about it, but as I've said, maybe I am stucked in some core concepts.

Comment: @IgorVeloso Are you trying to return `Flux<ResponseEntity<Person>>`?

Comment: Yes @SukhpalSingh, and that ResponseEntity with just a 404.

Comment: I think the getAll can return a general `Flux<>`, and define an exception and throw the exception as you needed, and handle the exception and set status code.

Comment: Have to agree with @Igor that all of the annotated controller examples I've found of a "getAll" web service method implementation either return a simple `Flux` and ignore error conditions (for example, directly passing on a MongoDB `.findall()`) or layer on `ResponseEntity` and sometimes `ResponseWrapper` with little explanation. I just want one example that shows a real error-handling implementation that Spring would recommend.  What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the function `collectList()` and `flatMap()`.
like this:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> listPeople(ServerRequest request) { 
                Flux<Person> people = repository.allPeople();
                return people.collectList().flatMap(p->
                    p.size() < 1 ?
                        ServerResponse.status(404).build()
                       :ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(p))
                ); 
        }
```